Bokeh server - memory leaks when on_event is used
I need to execute a Python callback when the ranges are changed. For that, I have to run a Bokeh application on a Bokeh server. I'm using Bokeh 3.4.0.
Everything works fine if I run the following code from Jupyter Notebook.
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.events import RangesUpdate
from bokeh.server.server import Server
import numpy as np

def bkapp(doc):
    fig = figure()
    x = np.linspace(-6, 6)
    y = np.cos(x)
    source = ColumnDataSource({"x": x, "y": y})
    line = fig.line("x", "y", source=source)
    
    def ranges_update(event):
        x = np.linspace(event.x0, event.x1)
        y = np.cos(x)
        line.data_source.data.update({"x": x, "y": y})
        
    fig.on_event(RangesUpdate, ranges_update)
    doc.add_root(fig)

# In Jupyter: everything is OK
output_notebook()
show(bkapp)

However, If a modify that code to be run from a standard python interpreter, I'm going to experience a memory leak. So far, only the browser crashed...
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.events import RangesUpdate
from bokeh.server.server import Server
import numpy as np

def bkapp(doc):
    fig = figure()
    x = np.linspace(-6, 6)
    y = np.cos(x)
    source = ColumnDataSource({"x": x, "y": y})
    line = fig.line("x", "y", source=source)
    
    def ranges_update(event):
        x = np.linspace(event.x0, event.x1)
        y = np.cos(x)
        line.data_source.data.update({"x": x, "y": y})
        
    fig.on_event(RangesUpdate, ranges_update)
    doc.add_root(fig)


# In a standard python interpreter: memory leak
server = Server(bkapp, num_procs=1)
server.start()
server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
server.io_loop.start()

Interesting, the server starts just fine if I comment out fig.on_event. This is the first time that I needed to launch a server from outside Jupyter. I must be doing something wrong. But what?

You'll need to provide a lot more detail about what exactly you measured, and how, on what platform. I ran your code and rapidly updated the range with a pan tool for a minute straight (many hundreds of range events) and noticed no perceptible changes in memory usage in either the Python process or the Safari browser process during that time.

Ubuntu 22.04, Python 3.10.12, Firefox 124.0.2. Measured RAM usage from system monitor, could see it spike from 6GB to 15GB in less than a couple of seconds.

Interesting. Now that I've rebooted the system, I'm not experiencing that issue any longer. Maybe it's some kind of cache problem...Previously I had attempted to start the server several times, but it failed due to errors into bkapp, which I then solved...
